# Google Sheets Query Column Reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to reference a column in a query to that matches that column data, without success.

I was able to write the following that works fine when I reference each cell where F matches G:

=query(Sheet1!A:T,"Select C,D,B,E,F where B = 'Removal' AND F matches '"&G1&"' or B = 'Removal' and F matches '"&G2&"'")

I am trying to reference the entire column and have used this following query with success, but in this case it is not resulting in the full data or it ends in a data cannot be coerced error:

=query(Sheet1!A:T,"Select C,D,B,E,F where B = 'Removal' AND F = '"&JOIN("' AND F = '",SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("||",1,G1:G),"||"))&"'")

The weird thing about this last one is that if I use "NOT F=" (AND NOT F = '"&JOIN("' AND NOT F = '",SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("||",1,G1:G),"||"))&"'")) it find all of the data that I'm trying not to pull, correctly (the data that I don't want)

working: for each cell in G: F matches '"&G1&"'
not working: for the entire column G: F = '"&JOIN("' AND F = '",SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("||",1,G1:G),"||"))&"'
not working: a column on another sheet: F matches '"&Sheet2!L:L&"'")
not working: import range column reference also not working: F matches '"&importrange("https:","Sheet2!L:L")&"'")

Comment: Show some sample data and desired output. You may also share a sample google-sheet here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're data is organised. You may try with this, just using TEXTJOIN. Please upload more information for a more specific answer

```
=query(Sheet1!A:T,"Select C,D,B,E,F where B = 'Removal' AND F = '"&TEXTJOIN("' AND F = '",1,G1:G)&"'")
```

Comment: That didn't work either. It does work for the not results NOT F = '"&TEXTJOIN("' AND NOT F = '",1,G:G)&"'")

Comment: Could you share same sample sheet to test it?

Comment: Thank you Martin but I found a solution here: 
=query(Inventory!A:T,“Select C,D,B,E,F where B = ‘Removal’ AND F matches '”&ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(“|”,G:G))&“'”)